# Scrolling in tmux in emacs

Tags: scrolling

I'm using emacs to run ansi-term with an ssh'ed tmux inside. I can scroll using my prefix `C-b + [` as per [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux), but I would like to be able to scroll with the mouse immediately.

This seems to work if I'm doing it in a terminal outside of emacs, so I'm wondering what steps are necessary when doing it within emacs.